# Reading text files, for in while vs while in for (java)

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop, java.util.scanner

This is a very easy code sample of an exercise for school. I got it to work, but I don't understand why my first idea didn't work. My first idea was the while loop in the double for loop (see comments /* */). If I used those loops it gave me an array back that was filled with zeros (there is a file integer.txt with random numbers in the same direction, that's not the problem).

Has it something to do with sc.hasNextInt()? I really don't understand why it works in this way and not the other.

Thanks for explaining in advance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String filename = "integer.txt";
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(filename);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

    int[][] getallen = new int[2][5];

    /*for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
                getallen[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }*/



    while(sc.hasNextInt()){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                getallen[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            System.out.print(getallen[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    System.out.println("Ok.");
    sc.close();
 }
```

Comment: Whatever you are trying with this code your `for` loops are unnecessary. you do not need them. you just need to play with index of array

Comment: Ok, but I must cycle through the indexes in some sort of way and the exercise was to put the numbers in a 2x5 array, so I don't really see another option here..

Comment: you could do something like this `int i=0,j=0;
  while(sc.hasNextInt()){
   getallen[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
   if(j==5) {
    i++;
    j=0;
   }
     }`

Comment: Seems weird to write to me... Is this actually better than the for loops? I've learned to use the for loops when I know how many spaces I must fill and learned to use a while loop when unknown to fill arrays...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your while loop i and j never move on, so within your while loop you were constantly over-writing the same positions inside `getallen`.

Just trace through what the code does and it should be obvious. i and j are 0. It then loops through pulling everything from the scanner and setting it into getallen[0][0]. It's then exhausted the scanner so it moves on with 0,0 containing the last scanner value. For every other step (unless something new comes into the scanner) hasNextInt() returns false so it never even executes and getallen[i][j] is not modified, which means it keeps its default value of 0.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, in the first case the while loop loops through all the numbers in the text file and only saves the last number of the 10 numbers in the array?

Answer (score 1):

Why

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            while(sc.hasNextInt()){
                getallen[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
```

this code did not work?

Because as soon as it hits your while loop it will overwrite same index values again and again.